# lightning datatable does not show any data, just empty lines

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable

Screenshot attached below:[image]

cmp file:

```
 <aura:component description="leaderboard" controller="WordshuffleRecordController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="reclist" type="Wordshuffle_record__c[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchRecords}"/>

    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.reclist}"
                         columns="{!v.reclist}"
                         keyField="Id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>

</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({

    fetchRecords : function (component, event, helper){
        helper.fetchRecordsHelper(component, event, helper);
    }
});
```

Helper:

```
({

    fetchRecordsHelper : function (component, event, helper){
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Player name', fieldName: 'PlayerName', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Score', fieldName: 'Score', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Reshuffles amount', fieldName: 'ReshufflesAmount', type: 'text'},
        ]);
        debugger
        var action = component.get("c.getRecordList");
        action.setParams({
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.debug("AAAAA" + response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.reclist", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
});
```

apex:

```
public with sharing class WordshuffleRecordController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<wordshuffle_record__c> getRecordList(){
        return [SELECT Id, Player_name__c, Score__c, Reshuffles__c FROM wordshuffle_record__c];
    }
}
```

Comment: At a guess, I'd say your fieldNames in your `v.mycolumns` need to match your field api names

Comment: @NickCook, thank you very much for usefull comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Nick's answer, columns="{!v.reclist}" should be updated to columns="{!v.mycolumns}" in lightning:datatable

Comment: Problem solved, thank you a lot :)